# PIctureBox to display images one after the other

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, picturebox

my program is supposed to load a picture from a third party application, display it as it is in a PictureBox. Then modify the image through some image processing algorithm and display the resulting image in the same PictureBox. Then fetch another image from the external system, display it, process it, display the result and so on and so forth. All this should result in the user seeing the images one after with a few seconds delay between them.

Is it possible to do this in Windows Forms (the project is coded in C++/CRL)? If so, how can I do it?

the code I have done so far looks like this (Im only displaying the chunks of code that I believe are relevant to understand what I want to achieve):

```
private: Bitmap^ image1;

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

 //connecting to the third party application
 PImage PI;
 PI.EstablishConnection();  

 //setting image parameters
 PI.setImageParameters(x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll); 


//retrieving image data 
int W = PI.returnCols(); 
 int H = PI.returnRows();

//updating Bitmap object as per image data       
 image1 = gcnew Bitmap (W, H);

//....

//function to modify the display and load the new image in pictureBox
ModifyDisplay (image1->Height, image1->Width, image1, PI);
pictureBox1->Image = image1;

//...
//process current image using some algorithms

//modify current image as per the processing and display it
ModifyDisplay (image1->Height, image1->Width, image1, PI);
pictureBox1->Image = image1;

//...fetch a new image
//function to modify the display and load the second image in pictureBox
ModifyDisplay (image1->Height, image1->Width, image1, PI);
pictureBox1->Image = image1;


//...
//process second image using some algorithms

//...and so on
}
```

The result I get is that only the last image is displayed, all that goes on before does not show.

Comment: This is very basic in GUI programming.  A window doesn't repaint itself until your UI thread stops executing code.  It cannot do two things at the same time.  A bandaid is to call pictureBox1->Update().  As long as these calculations don't take more than a second or so you'll see the images.  If it takes longer than Windows gets sulky about your program being unresponsive and displays the ghost window, it will say "Not responding" in the title bar.  Perform these calculations in a worker thread instead for a real solution.

Comment: thanks for the help with this. I guess I have no choice but go multithreading

Comment: btw, the  pictureBox1->Update() thing works and until I manage to make the threads thing work it's better than nothing (altho it is not really an ideal solution, as you pointed out. BUt I have never done multithreading so it's taking me some time to figure things out). THanks so much again!